# ScheduledExecutorService on many long tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I am using ScheduledExecutorService on java to handle events that are requested from the client to the server. The server hosts multiple clients, thus many requests need to be handled. When there are 10 clients on the request(means they are currently using an event scheduled by ScheduledExecutorService) - The 11th client may not be able to perform a request because the client will reject it due to it maxing out on core pool size(currently 10 on my end).

My question is - How do I deal with this sort of problem? I thought about increasing my core pool size but the server is likely to have about ~100 concurrent requests that use ScheduledExecutorService at the same time, so I do not think this is appropriate solution to it. Is there an alternative method to deal with many long tasks, like the case I just described?

Comment: The problem that you are trying to solve is, how to build a _scalable_ service. At some point, there's no way to work around the fact that you have more clients than your hardware can handle. Only solution is to get more or bigger hardware. At some point, you'll have more clients than _any_ single server can handle. At that point you have to turn to "cluster computing," or "cloud services." If you think you might run into those kinds of limits any time in the next couple of years, then it is not too early to start planning for it now.

Comment: Do you have scheduling, if 100 requests are using the  threadpool, why not a fixed thread pool?

Comment: ScheduledExecutorService is for running a task at a certain time, or running a task repeatedly. What does that have to do with clients who are coming and going? You should explain the bigger picture.

Comment: What does “on my end” mean?

Comment: Why are these tasks “long”? CPU intensive calculations? Or dead time waiting on an external database or remote service? This Question is much too broad, and unclear, for Stack Overflow. Voting to close. Please put more effort into drafting your question before posting.

Comment: I will try to explain better: I have a server that has clients connecting to it. I have a certain request from the client that makes invokes ScheduledExecuterService runnable so I can call this request asynced. When a client is in the executerservice, I lock the thread until it gets notified(I use ReentrantLock). The problem is - When a client idles inside the executerservice, it hangs on the thread and keeps it in the pool. If 10 clients idle inside the executerservice(10 is the core pool size) - The server will reject any other scheduledexecuterservices. @BasilBourque

Comment: I suspect you could use a listener pattern rather than blocking each task.